# Combining CucumberTestContext and TaggedHooks

Tags: java, spring, webdriver

I would like to combine CucumberTestContext (from cucumber-spring) for PageObject classes and TaggedHooks class. Anybody has success with that?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Cucumber For Java Book" helped:
"The cucumber-spring integration automatically associates all hooks and step definitions with a scope called cucumber-glue, but we’ll need to associate any objects that we’ve created to share state with that scope too."